# Swift 2.0 Subclassing a subclass of UIViewController and called convenience initializers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Have a bit of confusion regarding designated and convenience initializers for UIViewController in Swift 2.0/Xcode 7beta3. Our UIViewControllers are all defined in code, there are no Nibs

Currently class A inherits from UIViewController like this

```
class A : UIViewController {
    convenience init() {
        ...
        self.init(nibName:nil, bundle:nil)
        ...
    }    
}
```

Then class B inherits from class A and should override the convenience init and call its as super.init()

```
class B : A {
    convenience init() {
        super.init()
        ...
    }    
}
```

The compiler does not allow this with *Must call a designated initializer of the superclass '...'* error on `super.init()`

Comment: So what's the problem? The error message is clear. `super.init` is not a designated initializer - you yourself declared it a convenience initializer. Why are you surprised?

Comment: @matt - I am curious as to the best pattern to use here.  I am defining a convenience init method to do a dependency injection on `init()` for the subclass of UIViewController.  When I subclass the subclass, I want to be able to do the same dependency injection on `init()`, just modify some of the functionality.  This was an easy pattern to implement in ObjC.  I am asking what the best Swift pattern would be.  All of the answers, yours included, throw compiler errors in Swift 2.0 and don't seem to apply to the UIKit frameworks (or at least not to UIViewController)

Comment: Mine doesn't throw any compiler error in Swift 2.0 / iOS 9. I tried it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make your initializers designated, not `convenience`:

```
class A : UIViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(nibName:nil, bundle:nil)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("")
    }
}

class B : A {
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("")
    }
}
```

That gives you the inheritance structure you're looking for.

Comment: You might want to read my book, which explains the rules for class initializers (though really you hardly need to - all you have to do is listen to what the compiler tells you): http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_class_initializers

Comment: The compiler doesn't let me make init a designated initializer.  It forces me to add `convenience` with the error _Designated initializer for '...' cannot delegate (with 'self.init'); did you mean this to be a convenience initializer?_   If I add `required` it doesn't help to force it to be a designated init, its just required to be overridden by the subclass

Comment: You didn't copy and paste what I actually wrote. What I wrote works.

Comment: Do you need me to paste in a screen shot showing that my code compiles??? I'm happy to do it, but wouldn't it be better if _you_ copied my code and pasted it into your own app and proved it for _yourself_?

Comment: You are correct - I missed the `super.init(nibName:nil...` in `A.init()`.  My apologies.  I don't try to copy and paste code, I try to understand it and apply it to my own use case.  Thank you for your help

Comment: I gave you a link to the spot in my book that explains it. I urge you to read it; I really do think I explain it pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at these images found in the documentation.
[image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Art/initializersExample02_2x.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Art/initializerDelegation01_2x.png))</sub>

According to the image convenience initializers are not inherited.  So if you want to inherit you must make it a designated initializer.

```
class A : UIViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

class B : A {
     override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

At this Point you may wonder what the heck is the difference between a designated and convenience initializer?  Well, Convenience is used to call a designated initializer in the same class and you are suppose to use this to do some set up.

Comment: This triggers two errors `Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its super class` on the init and `Must call a designated initializer of the superclass '...'` on super.init()

Comment: I see you changed `self.init(nibName:...` to `super.init(nibName:...`  as @matt's answer below shows.  However, he had the correct answer before you updated your answer, so I'm marking his as answered.  I've removed my down vote, as your answer is now correct as well

Answer (score 0):

According to the document

> Rule 2 A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the same class.

From  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html(Initializer Delegation for Class Types)

You should call it's own initializer instead:

```
    class B : A {
       convenience init() {
         init()
         ...
       }    
    }
```

And init() is automatically inherit from it's superclass version

Answer (score 0):

Here are rules how communicating designated initializers and convenience initializers
**rule 1:**
A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from its immediate superclass.

**Rule 2:**
A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the same class.

**Rule 3:**
A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated initializer.

A simple way to remember this is:

Designated initializers must always *delegate up*.
Convenience initializers must always *delegate across*.